# Python class. Why is my program not printing/returning the text message upon user input?

Tags: class, methods, python-3.7

I am new to python and I am required to create a class that will simulate an SMS(text) functionality. I need to:

1. Create a list that will store messages,
2. Create method to add a text message and number message has been sent from to the list,
3. Create method to read the message and
4. Create another method to mark the message as read.

My issue is that upon choosing "send", the user must enter the text message & number and store these in the list. When choosing "read", the program must return the selected message from the list with the associated number, but when choosing "read" the program returns nothing and continues to ask the user to select either send/read/quit the program.

Here's what I have done so far:

'''class SMSMessage(object):

```
        def __init__(self, messageText, fromNumber, hasBeenRead = False):
        self.hasBeenRead = hasBeenRead
        self.messageText = messageText
        self.fromNumber = fromNumber

       def MarkAsRead(self):
       if self.hasBeenRead == False:
          self.hasBeenRead = True

       def __str__(self):
       return f"""
       Message: {self.messageText}
       Number: {self.fromNumber}
       """             

SMSStore = [] 

def add_sms(messageText, fromNumber):
    sms1 = SMSMessage(messageText, fromNumber)
    return SMSStore.append(sms1)


def get_message(index):
SMSStore[index]
SMSMessage.MarkAsRead(SMSStore[index])
return SMSMessage.__str__


userChoice = ""

while userChoice != "quit":
    userChoice = input("What would you like to do - read/send/quit? ")

if userChoice == "read":
    num = int(input("Enter the index of the message: "))
    get_message(num - 1)

elif userChoice == "send":
    message = input("Please enter your message to send.\n")
    number = int(input("What is the sender's number:\n"))
    add_sms(message, number)

elif userChoice == "quit":
    print("Goodbye")
else:
    print("Oops - incorrect input")
```

Comment: What's your *question*? This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; what's the *problem* with what you've shown.

Comment: I cant seem to print out the message that I have appended to the list. When selecting to read the messages, its supposed to return the message and the number from the SMSstore list I have created.

Comment: So give a [mcve] of that, what does *"can't"* mean exactly?

Comment: Upon choosing "send", the user must enter message and number and store these in the list. When choosing "read", the program must return the selected message from the list with the associated number but when choosing "read" the program returns nothing and continues to ask the read to select either rsend/read/quit the program.

Comment: So [edit] the question to illustrate that issue.